# How do I use some data from a python script in a JavaScript program?

Tags: javascript, python

```py
import requests
import math
    api_addr = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=5da47c441c88cfac88086c508e1aefab&q='
    city = input ('City Name? ')
    url = api_addr+city
    js_dat = requests.get(url).json()
```

This is my python code, this program basically pulls out some weather info. On the JavaScript end, I have not made a script yet.
I wanted to ask if I can use data from **js_dat** which will contain data in the *json* format, in JavaScript.
Thank you = )
PS: ignore the input function. I need an input from JS.

Comment: Yes, you can, as long as you return it in a valid JSON format

Comment: @wentjun is there a direct way to import data from python into JavaScrpit (sorry I am quite new to JavaScript)

Comment: You can send it via HTTP requests. You will probably need to set it up on your local server if you wish to test it out though

Comment: Do you need the python at all?   You can do that easily in JavaScript... unless to hide your appid

Comment: @Ctznkane525 ooooh well I realized that I did not hide the appid *in my question* XD... Sure thing I can do the same in JavaScript but uummm... it was a challenge from my father to use Python and JS. Thank You.

Comment: JSON.parse(js_dat) in js.